# Using DbContext to Get Children Count and map to property

Tags: entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

I have the following object tree where each plan which is a parent to a child of  comments & concerns. On the client i really don't care about the details 90% of time time and thus the comments are lazy loaded when expanded on a per dicipline basis.  But I need a little meta data about them for the current feature I'm working on.

```
[DataContract]
public class Plan
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Ton of properties

}

[DataContract]
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public bool IsConcern { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public bool IsResolved { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Discipline { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Plan_Id { get; set; }

    //Other properties
}
```

What I would like to do is something like this

```
[DataContract]
public class Plan
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Ton of properties

    public int Discipline1UnresolvedConcernCount?  { get; set; }
    //... Discipline2.... Discipline 8


}


    modelBuilder.Entity<Plan>()
        .Ignore(x => x.IsIntegrated)
        .Ignore(x => x.Discipline1UnresolvedConcernCount)
        .Ignore(x => x.Discipline2UnresolvedConcernCount)
```

The service

```
public class PlansController : BaseODataController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Look up a Plan record by ID
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">ID for the Plan</param>
    [EnableQuery]
    [Authorize]
    public SingleResult<Plan> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        using (CreateTimedTelemetryTrace($"key:{key}"))
        {
            IQueryable<Plan> result = DataContext.Plans.Where(bu => bu.Id == key)
           //Improve Query to get counts


            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do what im wanting to do, and is it clean?

Comment: No matter what you will have to make either another call to the db or use a join to get the counts. I'd use a navigation property `Plan.Comments` and then utilize `.Include()` to handle the join.

Comment: That's kind of what i figured. The original designer shared a class between OData model and EDM model. Trying to prevent Odata from grabbing it. I hope i dont have to build out an entire DTO architecture over a single property.

Comment: Another (possibly hackish) option is to create PlanWithComments that inherits Plan, and use raw sql to hydrate it with `DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<PlanWithComments>(sql)` having your raw `sql` containing your join

Comment: @Seth Its not clear what count are you excepting? Are you expecting `Plans` count or `Comments` count? Please make it clear?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I want Comments count returned as part of plans, but i don't care about any records that dont have IsConcern set to true.

Comment: All plans or single plan?

Comment: Just when i get a single Plan